# Add/attach a field to all content types

Tags: 7, entities

I know that I can attach a field to any content type. I have to attach a field to all content types in a my site which are more than 40 content types. It is hard for me to attach this field manually. I'm seeking for an automated way to do this. Is there any module to do that?

Comment: how many content types you have? In Drupal you can create a new field in any content type and then reuse the field with another content type.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. Have you looked for any module on Drupal.org before asking here? As @Aboodred1 said, you can manually add a field to any content type, once you created it for the first time. Is there any reason you need a module to do that?

Comment: Adding the same field w/ the exact same settings can get unmanagable on some projects when you have lots of content types, especially with filefield and cousins.  I don't think this is an unreasonable question.

Comment: @MPD - 40 content types is not so bad, but I agree, it can be a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Use your favourite SQL client and amnually populate `{field_config_instance}` table:

1. In Drupal, create field in one content type.
2. In your favourite editor create set of 39 queries (40 content types minus that one you worked out manually), with the same field values. Just leave id empty so autoincrement can work, and populate `entity_type` with your conetnt type names. I use spreadsheets to do that, first spreadsheet column is first query part, second is for the names of content types (obtained by querying `{node_type}`, third is for last part of the query.
3. Paste that query set into your SQL client and execute.